# Method call for Looper.prepare() and Looper.loop() for main UI thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading, looper

In android in case of UI Thread we just create `Handler` because main UI Thread already have its `Looper`.

I want to know where is call to `Looper.prepare` and `Looper.loop` for UI thread in framework code. I am digging framework code for hours trying to find that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in class `android.app.ActivityThread` in the `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to resort to using `Looper`, and you don't know the answer to the question, then you're probably doing something too complex. For the most part, Android handles that kind of stuff completely autonomously, you really shouldn't have to worry about it...

Just make the Handler from the GUI thread, putting in an onResume() or similar should work just fine.

```
Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    handler = new Handler();
}
```

Or else you could use the `runOnUiThread` command.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        the_textView.setText(someText);
    }});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I was looking for how Looper is setup for main UI thread for learning purpose.